# Leave provisions for part-time employees in Australia

Tags: employment, australia

What is the basis for the Fair Work Ombudsman's [assertions](https://www.fairwork.gov.au/leave/sick-and-carers-leave/paid-sick-and-carers-leave#how-much) that both:

- part-time employees entitlement to leave is pro-rata, according to total *hours* of service as compared to full-time employees, and,
- leave entitlements are unaffected by how the hours are *spread* over the week,

as pertains to *personal/sick/carer's* and *annual/recreational* leave?

If a HR system tracks accrued leave in units of *days*, should the reported balances get reduced if an employee adopts a compressed schedule (and increased if they revert to a standard schedule or otherwise reduce their average hours per work day)?

For context, quite different rules apply to other forms of leave (for example, for *long service leave* there is commonly a system of separate credits for full-time and part-time service; and for *domestic violence leave*, employees are entitled to the same amount whether they are full-time or even just casual). For *personal* and *annual leave*, the *Australian Federal [Fair Work Act](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2023C00036), part 2-2 (National Employment Standards) div. 6 & 7A* doesn't appear to distinguish between full-time and part-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MONDELEZ AUSTRALIA PTY LTD v AUTOMOTIVE, FOOD, METALS, ENGINEERING, PRINTING AND KINDRED INDUSTRIES UNION KNOWN AS THE AUSTRALIAN MANUFACTURING WORKERS UNION (AMWU) & ORS; MINISTER FOR JOBS AND INDUSTRIAL RELATIONS v AUTOMOTIVE, FOOD, METALS, ENGINEERING, PRINTING AND KINDRED INDUSTRIES UNION KNOWN AS THE AUSTRALIAN MANUFACTURING WORKERS UNION (AMWU) & ORS
[2020] HCA 29](https://www.hcourt.gov.au/assets/publications/judgment-summaries/2020/hca-29-2020-08-13.pdf)

> A majority of the High Court rejected the "working day" construction and instead held that what is meant by a "day" or "10 days" must be calculated by reference to an employee's ordinary hours of work. "10 days" in s 96(1) is two standard five-day working weeks. One "day" refers to a "notional day" consisting of one-tenth of the equivalent of an employee's ordinary hours of work in a two-week period. Because patterns of work do not always follow two-week cycles, the entitlement to "10 days" of paid personal/carer's leave can be calculated as 1/26 of an employee's ordinary hours of work in a year.

So we deal with “notional days” that are measured in hours equivalent to 1/26 (or 1/13 for annual leave for non-shift workers). What an employees actual shift is is irrelevant.

Similarly, their accrued hours don’t change if their normal hours of work change.

Comment: Thanks for the definitive source, how did you track it down?

Comment: I knew about it

Comment: I guess a prediction of how many work days the accrued hours will cover must depend on current average daily work hours.